# Why was this edit rejected?​

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11041034) to an answer that contained a list with a repeated item. My edit was rejected because it "deviates from the original intent of the post". Why would that be?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've applied the spirit of the edit in another fashion; one that avoids repeating information and also preserves what the original intent of the original post was.

Comment: Also, editing an answer of a user with 370k rep from 2009 makes non-robo reviewers wary.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> **TL;DR**: Assume that everyone reviewing your edit has tunnel vision, and is looking at only the red & green and *maybe* the line directly above and below it. They'll only look elsewhere if you explicitly tell them to in your edit comment.

Your edit was rejected because three people weren't paying enough attention. You have to understand, most reviewers don't really pay attention. **Reviewers are trained to look at red and green, and *only* red and green**.

All they saw was this:

[image]

and this:

> Comment: duplicate list item

Now, they look at that second thing, then looked at the red color and the 'list' around it. They never saw the list item *above* the code block.

---

That answers 'why' it was rejected. What you really want to know, though, is how you get these *approved*. I would have written the comment like this:

> Comment: Remove duplicated list item - see the item above the code block. The item I deleted was already mentioned.

You should stand a slightly better chance of having your edit approved if you're explicit, even painfully so, about what you did and why you did it.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I seem to be having an off weekend on Meta...the edit really shouldn't have been rejected.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I looked at the answer for too long to notice that the code block would distract someone from the first list item.

Comment: @Makoto No worries, it took me a few glances to figure out what was up here as well :)

Comment: @dramzy It would help if Undo used instead the "markdown" output instead of the rendered one... is *eye opening* ;)

Comment: I would vote to reject that edit if I'm one of the reviewers because...okay, I'm a bad reviewer.

Comment: @KevinGuan You'll notice that I never excluded myself from that group either :)

Comment: Without this answer I would've never found the duplicate item.

Comment: *They'll only look elsewhere if you explicitly tell them to in your edit comment.* Agreed 100%.  Even folks trying to be super diligent can miss things from time to time.  Although I sometimes spend several minutes on a review decision when the comments are very vague, I am sure I have missed stuff too.  Best way to guard against that is tell the reader up front exactly what you changed and why :) Not everyone will agree, but ... at least the reasoning behind it will be clear.

Comment: The takeaway from this answer and these comments is that edit reviewers need to spend more time reviewing suggested edits

Comment: @TylerH Definitely. That's hard to enforce, though.

Comment: Well, if I were one of the three people not paying attention – the following would be the reason: the code block below the first bullet is misaligned, making this look like two lists of one and three items respectively.