# Why was this suggested edit that removed redundant text, rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I normally do not care much about my rejected edits. It doesn't happen too often and usually it is because somebody with higher rep edits the post before mine edit is accepted, but this time it makes no sense to me. According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315853/why-was-this-edit-rejected), reviewers are trained to only check green and red parts.

In my recent edit I only removed the redundant sentence, which was there twice in the post, one after other. OK, it was not a great or any extremely needed edit, but are the reviewers really pushed to not to read my edit reason and do not care about context?

[Here is my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27803813).

Comment: Have you explained in the edit summary why you deleted it? (I also don't quite understand why that wasn't approved)

Comment: I guess they didn't notice the same sentence was in the post, again, just below. I suggest writing a more precise summary, maybe that could help reviewers understand your edit. But your edit was ok, anyway.

Comment: You can see i have added simple explanation "removed redundant text", I have believed that it is good enough explanation

Comment: Yeah, that's just a bad review. Your edit is good, and your explanation should have been sufficient. It should have been approved.

Comment: @Ruli Unfortunately, it's not enough. It sounds like you decided that information isn't relevant, so you deleted it, not that the information was present twice and you removed one copy of it. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: I rejected because I saw no reason why this part of the text was redundant. I read the sentence which explained what the author did, which usually is a good thing, so you know what the author already tried. Since the comment only said, "removed redundant text" and not why it was redundant, it wasn't clear enough to me why you would remove it. Reading the whole question now I see it's a duplicate sentence. So I should have accepted

Comment: Maybe you could have been a bit more precise, like "Removed sentence because it was copied and pasted below" but I would think it's enough. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Reviewers were incorrect. An even more descriptive edit summary might have improved the chances of it being reviewed correctly. But you didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: will try to be as precise as possible next time, maybe later, queue is full once again, thank you all for replies :)

Comment: "_rejected edit ... because ... somebody with higher rep edits the post before mine edit is accepted_". Are you sure about this? With 20k+ rep, I still have to wait untill a pending edit is approved/rejected, to edit a post.

Comment: @Teemu happens if two users start editing simultaneously. So user A submits and then user B submits. If A only submitted a suggestion and B submitted a full edit, then A's suggestion is automatically rejected. If user B arrived at the question when the edit was pending, they still have to wait for it to be approved/rejected.

Comment: @VLAZ I think concurrent edits are somewhat rare, rather a suggested edit is rejected, because it was edited in a review ..?

Comment: @Ruli I believe your edit is acceptable, and I wouldn't reject that for sure. That is a good enough reason for an edit, but please remember that edits should be substantial and you should always try to fix everything possible. I see there some basic and obvious gramatical issues and the formatting could be improved. Try to make it a habit to go over the whole post if already editing and not focus on a specific thing that caught your eyes in the first place

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are right, shame on me for not being precise. @Teemu check out for example [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27381608), the reason of reject is `This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.`. The subsequent edit happened almost 40 mins after first accept.

Comment: I cast my edits on the stream / I know not where they land / Perhaps upon the farthest shore / Perhaps Uttarakhand / Perhaps they're seen in Timbuktu / Perhaps in Paris gay / Perhaps reviewers kill them 'fore / They've seen the light of day / I pour my heart and soul into / Those words upon the screen / And should some unknown fiend delete / Well, then - I'll think they're mean! / But then I sigh and click again / Another question's shown / I edit, then I click, and then / To heav'n my edit's flown

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The reviewers got it wrong.

It happens.

What I dislike about your edit is that it neglects to fix the error message in the first paragraph:

> I am having many troubles trying to start training my model (a DCGAN). It is sending me the error : "'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'". I read this could be due to having both the tensorflow version 1.14.0 and the keras version 2.2 or superior.

I wouldn't have rejected your edit because of that, but try to be more thorough in your suggested edits, and correct as much as possible. In this case, properly formatting the error code so it can be easily read would be quite an improvement.

Answer (score 11):

[Another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403544/1997232) blame reviewers. I am going to blame you.

You added this comment

> removed redundant text

and *redundant* mean many things: long intro, welcomes/thanks, chatty parts, maybe anecdotes, etc. But it doesn't gives any hint for **what exactly** to look. At this point reviewers are guessing what was the problem, but is *duplicated sentence* included in their guesses is a question.

If I would be a reviewer myself then after reading comment I'd see what was removed (red text) and I will immediately spot "thanks" part. So far so good.

But then there is also another sentence with "tried to fix", "2.1.5" removed. And looking at that paragraph I don't see how this is redundant. It's essentially removing an important information about an attempt from that paragraph.

I wouldn't look at next paragraph and actually it's not guaranteed to be shown to reviwers. Nor I would check a complete post: it looks pretty much like **editor mistake**, perhaps he accidently removed extra sentence, and I would just click <kbd>Reject</kbd>.

---

Please be specific and accurate with what you did while your edits are reviewed. I would skip actions ("fixed", "removed", "added tags") and concentrate on actual problem. Reviewers can see what you did, but they may not come to same conclusion as you regarding problems with post.

Something like

> OP has repeated same sentence twice

or variants would do. Now it's an easy job for reviewer to just check this and accept.

Comment: This explanation would have more validity if we haven't established that reviewers basically [have tunnel vision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315855/792066).

Comment: This answer doesn’t indicate the reviewers made a mistake.  The edit was fine, had the review not been in a rush, and read the entire question they wouldn’t have needed a more detailed summary.

Comment: I am not saying another answer is wrong, reviewers could do better. But I think editors could do better as well by making their edit comments more clear. @SecurityHound, it's not about rush (or worser - robo-reviewing), comment field exist for a good reason.  Mechanic can find the problem and repair your car alone, but it surely helps him if you provide him with accurate details. And telling him you have "problem with wheel"  without telling its lying in trunk may lead to wasting him some time to check all other wheels first.

Comment: I already got such feedback in comments and the other answer as well, so yes you are right at this, I believe neither me neither the reviewers were 100% correct with this exact review, blame should be on both sides. I will for sure write better descriptions in future to avoid this.

Comment: The point is not to blame anybody here, but I totally support this answer. "redundant" is not a synonym for "duplicate", the latter also conveys the reason why the text is redundant: because it's repeated twice.