# Two suggested edits rejected because they don’t improve post quality—but they do

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I suggested two edits:

- [Plugin Bungeecord for chat prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30027547)
- [Can I make the inventory to be updated when clicking the item in another GUI, individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30010342)

Both suggestions were declined. That was a fear I had because they weren’t just fixing formatting or cleaning out unnecessary content. Let me explain.

**For [the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69041965/10952503)**, the OP made an answer ([Possible link 10k+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041965/plugin-bungeecord-for-chat-prefix/69062626#69062626)) to reply to my comment. The answer contained the code, which didn't answer their original question. So, I flagged it as *NAA*. The flag was accepted, and the answer removed.

Then, when reviewers in *suggested edits* saw my post, they unfortunately didn't see the answer where the code came from. I understand why they rejected it without the full context.

**For [the second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69466832/10952503)**, it's the same thing. I asked for more details in comment. I received them. Then, I edited the question to clean up the code, adding only the minimal reproducible example (instead of copying/pasting the edited class, or having a link that will be deleted in few weeks). I explained this in the explanation for the suggested edit. The first reviewer saw this, understood, and approved the suggestion, but not the others.

Both times, the code came from the OP, but they didn't take the time to edit their question. I took the time to do it, by including links to their code (or mentioning where it comes from).

Was that a good idea? Should I just ask for the OP to edit, and not do it myself? Or am I right, and these edits should have been approved?

**UPDATE**: The OP of the first question just approved the edit, so it seems good x). What about the second question?

Comment: For the first one, I learned the hard way to never flag the Answer before the edit has been approved. And explain very clearly that it's from the Answer on the post which was mistakenly posted in the Answer box instead of as an edit.

Comment: Perhaps a screen shot would convince some very diligent people, that want to give the time to load it. Personally, I just stopped editing. It takes too much effort and the rejections are just too easy. I suppose for me the benefit of improving the site with edits got squashed pretty thoroughly.

Comment: Honestly, I would just flag the answer as NAA, perhaps comment that they need to use the edit feature (on their question) and move on. The OP needs to make that edit, not the community. If the OP doesn't do the edit, then the question will likely  get closed, perhaps due to being unclear or not having an MRE.

Comment: Such as I answer to those question, I was trying to make it understandable for everyone who will comes after. That's why I take the time to edit. But I understand

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that the edit explanations are really easy to miss in the review queue. I make a point of looking at them if an edit doesn’t make sense to me, but a lot of reviewers overlook them entirely. And that’s probably because a lot of reviewers don’t offer _useful_ explanations. Unfortunately, that results in making these types of edits a bit risky before earning the full edit privilege.

Comment: For the first it's up to OP to learn to put the code into the question themselves, you would've been better off leaving a comment telling them how to use the site and flagging (at risk as others have said, but that's without seeing the context) and then not attempting to edit it into the question. Kinda the same case for the second (also read [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable))

Comment: @Nick: Good point regarding licensing on third-party sites. I probably wouldn’t have made that edit. But I’d likely have made the other edit, where the code had been posted as an answer—and then left a comment explaining what I’ve done and encouraging the OP to do it themselves in the future. And especially if they’re a new contributor. Sometimes, the best way to teach someone is to demonstrate how it should be done. (If they weren’t a new contributor, though, I’d be more likely to just _NAA_ and move on.)

Comment: Aside, at your current rate, you’ll hit that 2,000 reputation threshold pretty soon, and this won’t be an issue. I make a lot more edits like this—as well as nit-pickier improvements—now that I don’t need to worry about reviewers missing my explanations. I still made them before that on occasion, but I definitely weighed the effort against the risk of my edit being thrown out.

Comment: Oh ok Scratte. @Jeremy Caney I see, and I think the same because sometimes, specially on review, I don't edit because of not enough rep, and I look forward to 2k rep. With this question, I'm also questionning about if it was good idea to edit and reviewer just miss my intention or if it was just a bad idea or they was right to reject

Comment: @Elikill58 It's perfectly fine to edit in the content of the Answer box into the Question. I think it's not fine to reject that edit. Moderators have a button that will append an Answer to the Question, so the problem that Question authors will sometimes post additional information into an Answer box is certainly not a new issue. The problem is that people seem to think that it's fine to reject those edits. If the Question is good, then we don't need to "teach the user" to do it properly, in my opinion. We just need to fix it.

Comment: It's up to you to find out if you want to keep trying to fix what should be fixed and take the pushback through rejections. I decided it wasn't worth my time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For me it's only this time that appear. In 50 edit, I have 2 rejected because of conflict and 2 in this question. So I will continue, but maybe I will not make edit like that before 2k rep.

Comment: For what it's worth, @Elikill58, I appreciate you taking the time to invest back into the community via edits—and to also consider the merit of the review feedback. I think the community benefits from this level of conscientiousness.

Comment: Wait until you earn the full-edit privilege and then make such edits. I would never not vote to reject an edit proposal like the first one, no matter what the editor's comment says or what action the community deems *fine*.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Also, Oguz you was one of those who reject the first edit, and you just said you will not reject it ? Are you talking about the first, or the second ?

Comment: @oguzismail But.. that is just wrong. You can even see that Answer sitting there!

Comment: Hi folks! **Reminder that comments are not for extended discussion**. If you have an opinion on this matter, please share it by **posting an *answer*** in the box provided below.

Comment: @Elikill58 I said I would not not reject it.

Comment: @Scratte It's not. I can't see the answer in the review task screen, and can't be bothered to check answers before voting on an edit made to a question.

Comment: @Nick why should we wait for OP to do the edits? We have the tools to fix the situation, lets use them.

Comment: @Braiam We do have the tools, closure votes. (referring to the generic case)

Comment: @Nick Edits > close votes. That is the way. Close votes are reserved when only the OP can fix the issues that the question has. This is something anyone can fix.

Comment: @Braiam Keep telling yourself that

Comment: @Nick the fact that some users of SO have decided to be unconstructive using the sites features will no have any bearings on what I tell myself or others.

Comment: @CodyGray These kind of comments from mods are getting tiresome. How can an answer be an extended discussion? That doesn't make any sense. An answer is a monologue, not a discussion. And if comments aren't to be used for discussions, then where exactly on meta should things be discussed? It's very strange site design overall to provide a mandatory tag "discussion", then get upset when people actually start to discuss.

Comment: I think he was telling that some comments should be an answer, and instead of talking here, current comment should be on the created answer

Comment: So, is there a mod that can answer, and specially maybe do edit to make them question don't be closed? Should I ask for new edit? Wait until 2k rep such as said before with Jeremy ?

Comment: @Elikill58 sadly you are caught in the crossfire of two mindsets: people that use the tools to their best of abilities, and the others that are so afraid that they may mess it up that they obstruct others from using the tools the site presents. You may find solace in the help center: [If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) The help center is better than any user or moderator, because all actions should be based on stuff described there.

Comment: The given help center clearly say "*To add related resources or hyperlinks*". I add code (which is resource) given by the OP to their question. For me, I'm on-topic and such as there is mod that have almost all rights, I think they can help me in my disputed edits. Maybe they just will say that those edits don't should be UP, idk. But thanks for trying to helping me, I'm not affraid, just like "*that sad for edit and for those questions*"

Comment: @Lundin The "discussion" tag on Meta means that "discussion"-style answers are OK. In other words, on Meta, it's OK to post your opinion as an answer. It does *not* mean: "please engage in a bunch of noisy back-and-forth in the comments section". I do not know why you find these comments from mods to be unclear. For me, it is very clear. Scratte's original comment should have been posted as an answer, then all the related discussion could have been in comments to that answer, not the question. Same for Larnu's comment. Etc. It isn't that we hate discussion. It is the lengthy comment threads.

Comment: @CodyGray Discussion means dialogue. You have to do it with other people. The current meta format is indeed entirely unsuitable for such, but that's no fault of the users. Q&A style was never a good format for meta. The site could ditch voting, implement threaded comments and so on.

Comment: Not sure I agree. Voting is the #1 most important feature on the Meta site, probably more important than even posting. Threaded comments might be a nice feature to add, but there's a clever trick: post an answer with the opinion, then the comments underneath that answer become a dedicated thread to discussion about that opinion!

Comment: @CodyGray Voting is only important when you are actually interested in it... which is not necessarily the case for discussions and never the case for support- or bug requests. Anyway, this is drifting way off-topic so I'll stop here.

Comment: I rejected edit #1 for the reasons you guessed: I don't have 10k reputation so didn't know about any answer by the OP. It looked to me like you'd modified the (non-deleted) answer to guess at the OP's code, which made no sense to me. The edit summary "*Include code from his answer of this question*" (which I read when I got confused) did not help with the confusion. Without the context of the deleted answer, it looked like your edit deviated from the OP's intent so I acted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WaiHaLee. If you got confused, why don't skip and let 10k people see and do not be confused ? Because there is [no shame to skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/10952503) :)

Comment: I didn't skip because I took "his answer" to refer to the answer that I could see; because it looked to me like you'd edited the answer that I could see to fit the question, it seemed like you were guessing the OP's problem and putting words into their mouth so that the question would have code.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand. With this review side It's completly normal to reject the edit.

Comment: @CodyGray can you help me with the second edit ? Like approve it ? The first one have been approved by OP, but the second is still rejected, and so people downvote :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first have been approved by the OP, and the sceond by a moderator (thanks Cody Gray!).

Now, I hope people will stop downvote their question, because the issue with them are *-for me-* fixed.

Answer (score 20):

Adding code to the question poses some problems/risks when done by someone else than the OP:

- it can happen for not all code to be copied+pasted
- it can happen for extra characters to be mistakenly added after pasting
- the copied code might get into conflict with already existing code from the question
- the non-code part might need editing in order to fit within the question, which might slightly change OP's intent
- you might introduce licensing issues, especially if the code is brought from external sources (2nd linked question refers to pastebin code, and while pastebin won't likely cause issues, other external sources might)
- if you're under 2k, this puts a huge burden on the reviewers, as they'll have to verify bit-by-bit that you made the correct content transplant

As others have said in the comments, this operation should be left out for the OP itself, or maybe the mods (which likely have automated tools for the merge, if the code comes from an answer).

As a general rule, adding/editing/deleting code besides improving formatting, is not something that should be done by someone else. It's OP's code, ask them nicely to add it to the question.

If the OP doesn't want do do it, and

- the code is already on SO, and
- you know exactly what you're doing (see the first 4 bullets from the list above), and
- you have over 2k reputation,

then you might engage with the edit. Otherwise, leave it alone, it's unlikely your edit will salvage the question.

Comment: This would work, except that [the mods are not paying attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189562/do-reviewers-need-more-coffee#comment585560_189562), [nor the reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315855), not even the rest of the community. This has been a problem since the start: reviewers are so afraid of being banned from review that they would reject anything and everything that isn't fixing typos or formatting.

Comment: @Braiam, well, that might be another problem these days. But for the particular case in discussion, the reviewer actions were correct, IMO. If the OP can't be bothered to correctly add the code to their question, then others trying to solve a puzzle from pieces scattered in OP's comments and answers won't get us far in terms of having a question that deserves to be on SO.

Comment: @Cristik This is suppose to be a repository of Questions, not a place to teach users to behave. If the post can be salvaged and someone takes their time to do it, the last thing we need are people squandering that effort.

Comment: @Scratte of course there are exceptions, though myself didn't yet run into a question salvaged from a state like the one in discussion here, and that eventually became useful to other people than the OP. My point here is care to be taken when transplanting code, for the reasons enumerated above.

Comment: "if the code is intellectual proprietary, you also take responsibility of circulating that piece of code" The OP posted the code as an answer, so they already put it under creative commons license. As long as a reference to the (non)answer is included, it should be fine.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz while this might be true for code taken from a SO answer, things might be different if the code is taken from external sources, like in the case of the second linked question. Now, for that particular case I don't think that pastebin poses licensing problems, however other external sources might have other licensing systems.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase that bullet to licensing stuff rather than IP

Comment: @Cristik For answers, it's a self fulfilling prophecy. NAA as a delete reason is so weak that all but the most blatant gibberish sticks around forever. I as an expert might know what a lazy answerer was alluding to and can edit it, it might even be a good suggestion (but poorly described). The reviewers aren't willing or able to do the same legwork I did. I'll get a "deviates from intent" reject as a reward for filling in the blanks and cleaning up the site, not because I was wrong about their intent, but because a reviewer can't know if I was wrong. That's just broken, sorry.

Comment: If as a reviewer I cannot or don't want to verify the completeness or accuracy of an edit, I just click on skip and move on. I would not reject an edit.

Comment: This is why I always get very frustrated whenever edits are made to to put OPs code from some online code repo or editor into a question.  We have no idea if that code is the OPs or not.  The OP ***has*** to do it.  They have to be educated into doing it to.  If they don't, downvote and move on.

Comment: @zero298 that has a fixing: closing. But if  the information is already on the site, it's fair game. This case is the later, not the former.

Answer (score 2):

We've been having this argument for well over a decade now and it never changes... the people who're against editing are getting more vocal over time, but it's yet to result in changes to official policy or the community FAQs.

By adding the OPs code from an answer into the question *you did exactly the right thing* and the reviewers are incorrect. [This is a good edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30027547).

The [about page says](https://stackoverflow.com/about)

> Our goal is to have the **best answers** to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can **edit** them.

The [editing help page says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (my emphasis)

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> **Any time you see a post that needs improvement** and are inclined to suggest an edit, **you are welcome to do so**. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. **Common reasons for edits include:**
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without *changing* that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place**

[One of Stack Overflow's founders says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) (not my emphasis)

> **You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.**

Using the tools available to you, you followed the long-standing advice to improve the question and therefore everyone's experience of this site.

**Thank you, well done, and I hope this experience doesn't put you off continuing to improve things.**

Comment: You may want to add that it's fine as long as the license is agreeing with it :)

Comment: It was in an answer @Scratte. The licence is either identical or compatible between the question and the non-answer and therefore doesn't need to be mentioned.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My mistake. I got it confused with the another one with code from an external source. I think that turned out to be on a site with a permissive license.

Comment: No worries! I didn't want to comment on that one 'cause I couldn't be bothered to work out the entire diff :-). That one would be a skip from me.